# Getting access denied from S3 when calling cross account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have an AWS data account where I have an S3 bucket. I have several AWS worker accounts where I have AWS Lambda functions. I want the Lambda functions to push objects into the S3 bucket in the data account.

I have configured in the data account a role R1 that has S3 Full Access, and a policy that establishes a trusted entity with the worker accounts and gives those accounts `assumerole` access. I have also configured a bucket policy that gives R1 access to the S3 bucket.

In the worker accounts, I have configured a Role R2 for the Lambda function. That R2 role has a policy attached that says it can `assumeRole` R1. When I try to `putObject` from the Lambda function, I get `403 access denied`.

I have no idea where in this chain things are not working, the error is completely nondescript and useless, and every documentation I look at solely talks about how to do this through the console, whereas I am using CloudFormation to do this. I'm not sure how to even begin debugging this because I'm not sure of an easy way to emulate a Role and see what its doing. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying that the workers using R2 are able to **successfully** call `AssumeRole()` on R1? And it is when they use R1 to `PutObject()` that the error is occurring? Can you show us the relevant parts of your code, just to prove that it is actually calling `AssumeRole()`?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein actually you're right, I was not calling assumeRole

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach would be:

- Add a **bucket policy** to the S3 bucket in the Data Account. In the policy, grant PutObject permissions for the IAM Role used by each of the worker AWS Lambda functions.
- Grant permission in the **IAM Role** used by each of the worker Lambda functions to PutObject into the central bucket

That is, *both* accounts are permitting the access.

Then, the Lambda function can write directly to the bucket, without needing to assume an IAM Role.